# Tips for transplanting these habaneros

Tags: transplanting, peppers, habaneros

Longtime pepper lover but first time grower. I was gifted four habanero plants and I am wondering if it’s close to time to transplant them and I am wondering if anyone has tips for this.

[image]

I have looked at a lot of resources online and this is my small plan. I want to place two plants in five gallon grow sacks each and water when dry about half an inch into the soil. Assuming Mother Nature isn’t watering it for me.

I am concerned though with just how to do this. Would two plants be to many and also are these plants even ready? I believe they are a bit over watered from whatever store they were purchased from based on the slight wilting. We don’t seem to be forecasted any rain for over a week and a half so perhaps it’s better to transplant them after they get a bit dryer, soil is currently pretty damp, or do it now while still damp?

While I have heard pepper plants are fairly forgiving I am eager to at least try and not mess these up :)

Comment: They are small enough, transplant when you want. And I  suspect that the wilting means they werent watered enough.